# How to disable orientation change in MapActivity

Tags: android, android-maps

Here is the thing. I do need to do a long process after my MapActivity is started, I have a lot of GeoPoints to add to the map. Everything works fine, but I want to display a ProgressDialog, while my AsyncTask does the job in the background, so the user actually knows that something happens in that few seconds. Again, everything works just fine, until I rotate the phone while the ProgressDialog is alive. No problem I thought, I already dealed with this in another Activity, so I will just pass the Activity to the AsyncTask, which will then invoke the following line before the dialog is shown, so the Context in which I am showing the dialog, wont get destroyed prematurely thus producing a force close:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

...and I will just invoke this line after my dialog is dismissed:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

...so the user can rotate his phone again. Here comes my problem: it just won't work in a MapActivity, it will produce a NullPointerException on the NOSENSOR line. Is there any other way to temporarily disable rotation in MapActivities? I might just fix the whole thing to "portrait", but that is not what I want to do, if I could do it better.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the configuration(like orientation change) yourself. Add this to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the activity tag.

Then you can handle these config changes by putting following method to your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

}
```

Comment: guess Ill do it this way, unless someone can come up with a 1 line solution, like the one I mentioned :)